# problems manipulation dataframes in dictionary from pd.read_excel

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Good day all,
I have an excel with multiple sheets which I load via pd.read_excel into a dict object.
Each excel sheet contains some column names which are the same:

Like sheet1: ['IDx','IDy'], sheet2: ['IDx','IDy']

I usually use pd.concat in order to load everything into one data frame. This way same column names also get merged correctly.

But this way is not robust in the case that there is some accidental extra white space in one of the ID columns but they're actually meant to get merged with pd.concat.

like: sheet1: ['IDx','IDy'], sheet2: ['IDx','   IDy']

To tackle this problem I thought to iterate over each data frame from the excel dict and strip() the column names of white space and then pd.concat afterwards.

```
excel = pd.read_excel('D:\ExcelFile.xlsx', sheet_name=None)    

new_excel = {}

for name, sheet in excel.items():
    sheet = sheet.columns.str.strip()
    #print(sheet)
    new_excel[name] = sheet
    
print(new_excel)
```

output:

```
{'Sheet1': Index([      'IDx',         'IDy', ..... ]}
```

at this point I am stuck. I can't do anything with the new_excel dict. It seems that I am accessing each data frame incorrectly and just get the Index object. I can't get my head around this issue.

When trying to concat with new_excel:

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'pandas.core.indexes.base.Index'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

does this work?

```
new_excel = {}

for name, sheet in excel.items():
    new_columns = [str(col).strip() for col in sheet.columns]
    sheet.columns = new_columns
    new_excel[name] = sheet
```

Comment: No, sadly not. I have integers in my col names. I tried to circumvent this with another loop but failed so far to get it to work. I am not very good with this 

    for name, sheet in excel.items():
        for i in sheet: 
            if type(i) != int: 
                new_columns = [col.strip() for col in sheet.columns]
          
            else:  
                new_columns = sheet.columns
        sheet.columns = new_columns
        new_excel[name] = sheet
 `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'strip'`

Comment: I've edited. Check my comment on your answer below as to why the original might not have worked.

Comment: Just hat the chance to check your edit. It worked perfectly on the first try. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

No, sadly not. I have integers in my col names (Attribute Error: 'int' object has no attribute 'strip'). When trying to change the type of the columns I ran into trouble with key error and the indexes being messed up. I tried to circumvent this with another for loop but failed so far to get it to work. I am not very good with this

```
for name, sheet in excel.items():
    for i in sheet: 
        if type(i) != int: 
            new_columns = [col.strip() for col in sheet.columns]
      
        else:  
            new_columns = sheet.columns
    print(new_columns)    
    sheet.columns = new_columns
    new_excel[name] = sheet
```

still getting `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'strip'`

Error is clear but not the solution for me

Comment: That's because for each column (i), you're trying to perform the .strip() method on all columns (sheet.columns), so if any of the columns are type int, it will raise an error, even if the column you're currently iterating over isn't. Check my edited answer above.

Comment: Just hat the chance to check your edit. It worked perfectly on the first try. Thank you very much!